# Testing PySide Application using QProcess

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside, pytest

I have a PySide application that spawns a worker application in a `QProcess`. The worker performs a simulation and creates result files to be read by the main application. I want to spawn the worker, give time for it to work, and then check the output. In my test function (I'm using py.test, if that helps), I cannot find a way to wait for the worker without blocking the main thread, thus not allowing the worker process to start and run.

```
def test_worker_thread():
    application = Application()  # Waits for and loads result files
    application.worker.start()  # Runs in a new process

    # How to wait right here without blocking thread?

    <wait_code>

    assert_correct_data(application.worker.results)
```

For the section called "wait_code", I have tried:

- Creating a local object with one attribute called `done`. I connect the `worker.finished` signal to setting `done` to True. I then used a `time.sleep` loop to block wait for the worker to be done.

  ```
  class WaitObject:

      def __init__(self):
          self.condition = False

      def set_true(self):
          self.condition = True

  wait = WaitObject()
  application.worker.finished(wait.set_true)

  while not wait.condition:
      time.sleep(1)
  ```
- I googled for methods to test asynchronous Qt code, and I came across `QTest.qWait`, which I could use in place of `time.sleep()` without blocking the event loop. However, `qWait` is not included in PySide.
- I have also tried creating a new event loop, like in [this thread](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_wait_synchronously_for_a_Signal_in_Qt). However, this seems to block the event loop for `application`, so we cannot finish the `worker.start` function and load data while the worker is running.

  ```
  loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
  application.worker.finished(loop.quit)
  loop.exec_()
  ```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out option 3 actually works. My worker wasn't starting because of an unrelated error. Here is some skeleton code in its entirety:

```
def test_worker_thread():
    application = Application()  # Waits for and loads result files
    application.worker.start()  # Runs in a new process

    loop = QtGui.QEventLoop()
    application.worker.finished(loop.quit)  # Resume when worker done
    loop.exec_()  # Blocks at this line until loop quits

    assert_correct_data(application.worker.results)
```

I am going to work on an abstraction of this pattern. I am going to add a timeout using a singleshot `QTimer` that is connected to `loop.quit`, in case `worker.finished` is never called.

EDIT: Here is a [blog post](http://jdreaver.com/posts/2014-07-03-waiting-for-signals-pyside-pyqt.html) explaining in more detail.

Comment: Basically you used a signal. That way you are not waiting for the thread anymore but the thread is telling when it is finished. And this is indeed a good solution.